# How to identify a div id and trigger it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I got a problem with one of the sites with JavaScript, and I need to automate a click and then find out how many turns I got before I run out of them. As in, for example, let's say I have 8 turns. So what I would need is to automatically have JavaScript to trigger said div id, 8 times. (As in, I add like this)
Link:https://jsfiddle.net/yxsgp8tc/

```
<body>
   <button id="test">Test</button>
   <p>
      On box should be number of tests
   </p>
   <form>
       <label><input type="text"/>00-99</label>
       <button>
            trigger it
       </button>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `trigger a div` ? And what do you mean by `automate a click` ? Are you talking about a testing environment? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a total noob to javascript, that is why I ask you for your help, if you want to give it to me.

Comment: We cannot help you, when we don't understand what do you want.

Comment: As in, let's say I got 8 turns. I would need the JS program to trigger the button with ID test 8 times.

Answer (score 1):

in plain javascript, you would target unique elements (using an id) by using `document.getElementById('<element_id')`. If you wanted to target a class, you would `document.querySelector('.<class_name>')` for the first instance of the class, or `document.querySeletorAll('.<class_name>')`

Also, your input tag was misspelled "imput", and is a singleton tag so you don't have to close it off.

Assuming you wanted a way to trigger a click event, here's a basic example:

```
<head>
    <script>
    const test = document.getElementById('test');
    const trigger = document.getElementById('trigger')''

    test.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const num_test = document.getElementById('num_tests').value;
  
        for (let i = 0; i < num_test; i++) {
            trigger.click();
        }
    });
    
    trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('trigger clicked');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
    <p>
        On box should be number of tests
    </p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="num_tests" value="">
        <button id="trigger">
            trigger it
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/qr1z3d6e/2/`

Comment: Thank you Frank, that's what I needed

Answer (score -1):

first in the jsfiddle.net link there are some errors such as `imput` instead of `input`.
I haven't tested it, but if I understand correctly is it something like this? try it.

```
<body>
  <input id="myinput" type="text">00-99</input>
  <button id="clickme">
</body>

 <script>
   var button = document.getElementById("clickme"),
   count = 99;
   var myInput = document.getElementById("myinput")

   button.onclick = function(count){
     count -= 1;
   myInput.innerHTML = "00 " + count;
   };
 </script>
```